# Relating to subset assignment, how can this syntax be useful?

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I have been reading the R Language Definition file.
Recently I came across this syntax as a shortcut for subset assignment.  For example

```
> x <- c(1:16)
> x[3:5] <- 13:15
> x
[1]  1  2 13 14 15  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

instead of

```
> x <- c(1:16)
> x[3:5] <- x[13:15]
> x
```

This can be made much more elaborate as in

```
> x[3:5] <- 13:15 + 15
> x
[1]  1  2 28 29 30  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
> x[3:5] <- 13:15*15:15
> x
[1]   1   2 195 210 225   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

To me this seems like a neat trick.  On the other hand it seems like using it will inevitably lead to unreadable code.

Does anyone know of a good reason to use this kind of feature?

Comment: You have to implement values in parts of an object all the time. This is like asking if it is a good idea to use a pen to write things down:)

Comment: Maybe I need to edit my title.  I am asking about the specific syntax outlined in my post.  Let me know if there is a better name for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset assignment is invaluable when you only want to replace some of the elements of an object in R.

Consider this example when programming. We have an S3 generic and a method. We might like to print the call in the output

```
foo <- function(x, ...) {
    UseMethod("foo")
}

foo.default <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    obj <- list(fitted.values = mean(x, na.rm = na.rm),
                call = match.call())
    class(obj) <- "foo"
    obj
}

print.foo <- function(x, ...) {
    writeLines(strwrap("Call:"))
    print(x$call)
    cat("\n")
    print(fitted(x), ...)
}
```

Look what happens when we use this though:

```
R> set.seed(2)
R> foo(runif(10))
Call:
foo.default(x = runif(10))

[1] 0.5496559
```

It would be nicer if the call was just `foo(x = runif(10))`. We can rewrite our default method to resent the matched call using subset assignment:

```
foo.default <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    obj <- list(fitted.values = mean(x, na.rm = na.rm),
                call = match.call())
    obj$call[[1]] <- as.name("foo") ## here is the edit
    class(obj) <- "foo"
    obj
}
```

Which gives the much nicer:

```
R> set.seed(2)
R> foo(runif(10))
Call:
foo(x = runif(10))

[1] 0.5496559
```

The point is, that I don't need to know how to generate the appropriate matched call in it's entirety, I can just update one aspect of the call using subset assignment. This is a real boon when you just need to alter one or a few components of an object and not just a trick.

Comment: I am new to R and I definitely learned some stuff from reading your code.  Your answer is not quite getting at my question though.  Please see my comment above.

Comment: @kalu well I used the same syntax (I need `[[` instead of `[` because the call is a list but that is a minor usage issue) as you. I don't think it leads to unreadable code and I don't think it is a tweak.

Comment: I realized I was not interpreting the example correctly.  For some reason the way I was reading the example I though `x<-2*1:4; x[1:2]<-3:4` would set `x[2]` equal to `8`.  Clearly that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are objecting to overwriting the original object then try the following which returns a new object and leaves x unchanged:

```
xnew <- replace(x, 3:5, 13:15*15:15)
```

Comment: Interesting.  What is the difference between `replace()` and `"[<-"`?  For example `x.tst <- array(1:6, c(2,3)); s.tst <- array(0, c(2,3));  s.tst[1:3] <- 1; "[<-"(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)`?

Comment: @kalu, Assuming you meant `"[<-"(x.tst, c(s.tst==1), 0)` that statement overwrites `x.tst` with a new value whereas `replace(x.tst, c(s.tst==1), 0)` returns the value instead.

Comment: Actually, that is not the case.  See my other post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346101/replace-vs)

Comment: @kalu, Good point.  They are identical: `x.tst.1 <- x.tst.2 <- x.tst; identical("[<-"(x.tst.1, c(s.tst)==1, 0), replace(x.tst.2, c(s.tst)==1, 0))` gives `TRUE` and `identical(x.tst.1, x.tst)` and `identical(x.tst.2, x.tst)` are each `TRUE` as well.

Comment: @kalu, Good point.  They are identical: `x.tst.1 <- x.tst.2 <- x.tst; identical("[<-"(x.tst.1, c(s.tst)==1, 0), replace(x.tst.2, c(s.tst)==1, 0))` gives `TRUE` and `identical(x.tst.1, x.tst)` and `identical(x.tst.2, x.tst)` are each `TRUE` as well.  At any rate the key point relative to your post is that regardless of whether you use `replace` or `[<-(...)` they don't have side effects which is the dangerous aspect of what you were referring to in the question.