# replace() vs "[<-"?

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I recently stumbled across `replace()` and `"[<-"`.  They seem to have similar functionality, for example with `"[<-"` I can do something like this:

```
        > x.tst <- array(1:6, c(2,3))
        > s.tst <- array(0, c(2,3))
        > s.tst
             [,1] [,2] [,3]
        [1,]    0    0    0
        [2,]    0    0    0
        > s.tst[1:3] <- 1
        > "[<-"(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)
             [,1] [,2] [,3]
        [1,]    0    0    5
        [2,]    0    4    6
        > x.tst
             [,1] [,2] [,3]
        [1,]    1    3    5
        [2,]    2    4    6
```

Can somebody help to clarify the difference?  What are the strengths of `replace` vs `"[<-"` and vis versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're basically exactly the same thing. If you look at the source code of replace, you'll see :

```
function (x, list, values) 
{
    x[list] <- values
    x
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So replace is nothing else but a wrapper around `[<-` :

```
> replace(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    5
[2,]    0    4    6
```

Using `[<-` can give you a speedup if you need to do this a million times, as you lose the extra call to the wrapper function. But it's really marginal, so it's a matter of choice. I would say that `replace()`is a bit more readible

Btw, `x.tst[s.tst==1] <- 0` is quite more readible than `"[<-"(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)` . No reason to use that construct, unless you want to save the result in a new dataframe.

To clarify, as @Andrie pointed out, both with `replace()` and `"[<-"(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)` you get a copy of the whole x.tst with the relevant values changed. So you can put that in a new object. This is contrary to `x.tst[s.tst==1] <- 0`, where you change the values in x.tst itself. Mind you, it doesn't save on memory, as R will make internally a copy of x.tst before doing the manipulation.

Timing results :

```
> system.time(replicate(1e6, replace(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)))
   user  system elapsed 
  12.73    0.03   12.78 

> system.time(replicate(1e6, "[<-"(x.tst, s.tst==1, 0)))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.42    0.02    6.44 

> system.time(replicate(1e6, x.tst[s.tst==1] <- 0))
   user  system elapsed 
   5.28    0.02    5.32
```

Comment: +1 One small difference, I think, is that `replace(x, list, ...)` doesn't modify x, whereas `x[list] <- ...` will modify x.  So `replace` can be used slightly differently.

Comment: Whew. You guys should write a book or something!

Comment: @Andrie : indeed, added to the answer

Comment: @Joris Meys Its amazing how often looking at source code can help to clarify things.  Thanks!

Comment: That's not actually amazing at all IMO